# React Typescript error TS2332: type '{...}' is not assignable to type '{...}'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically render a child component using a string I get in the props of the parent component. I'm creating an object and using an interface:

```
interface compsInterface {
  [key: string]: React.ComponentType<ComponentAProps> | React.ComponentType<ComponentBProps>;
}

const comps: compsInterface = {
  compA: ComponentA,
  compB: ComponentB
}

const ChildComponent = comps[type]
```

But when I call the component in the html the linter tells me there is the following error (I abbreviated object attributes):

```
<ChildComponent {...childProps} />
ERROR: Type '{all attributes}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ComponentAProps & { children?: ReactNode; } & ComponentBProps & Record<...>'.
  Property 'required attribute from component b' is missing in type 'ComponentAProps' but required in type 'ComponentBProps'.
```

Component A and Component B have both different attributes from each other. It is saying that an attribute that is required in component B is missing in component A.

I'm not sure if I'm getting all this union types well. I just want to be able to tell the interface that it should either use one component type or the other without having to put all attributes optional.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are using Union type you are trying to give opportunity for someone to add component that is any of two types, you will need to provide for each component in that object what type is it exactly, even though you have that `ComponentA` is of its type.

This happens because in your type `CompsInterface` you define union type and after that when you use component from `comps` you will have all of the component by of type `React.ComponentType<ComponentAProps> | React.ComponentType<ComponentBProps>`

So to prevent that you can add this:

```js
...

const comps: compsInterface = {
  compA: ComponentA as React.ComponentType<ComponentAProps>,
  compB: ComponentB as React.ComponentType<ComponentBProps>
}

...
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the error continues to happen. However, I removed the interface and I got a different error, that could be easier to solve. The error is on this line: const ChildComponent = comps[type] And it says: Element implicit has an 'any' type. which is referring to the key lookup I do.

Comment: Hmm, what is value of `[type]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `interface compsInterface` tells you that its members are **either** a component that takes `ComponentAProps` **or** a component that takes `ComponentBProps`  You don't know which one it is. So you have to supply **both** `ComponentAProps` and `ComponentBProps` in order to guarantee that your component gets the props that it needs.

This interface introduces a type-widening that is really not necessary.  You know that the keys on `comps` are only `compA` and `compB` instead of every `string`.  You know that `comps.compA` is always `ComponentA` and never `ComponentB`.  If you don't include a type annotation on `comps` at all then Typescript will be able to know those things too.

---

I'm not sure exactly what your use case is. If you want to access `const ChildComponent = comps[type]` then you want your `type` variable to have a type which extends `keyof typeof comps` which is the union `"compA" | "compB"`.  If the type for `type` is just the union and not a specific key `"compA"` or `"compB"` then you will still need to provide the props for both components, as explained above.